# Does Java Blocks processes created by runtime.exec?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

From Java code I am calling my script file following way,

```
Process  process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /usr/local/garner/garnerd start");
int status = process.waitFor();
```

garnerd script code is given below(which in turn calls garner.sh):

```
function start() 
{
    sh /usr/local/garner/garner.sh > /usr/local/garner/log/garner.log &
    echo "Garner is started"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: garnerd {start|stop|restart|status|reconfig}"
        exit 1
esac
exit $retval
```

Garner shell script(garner.sh) source is:

```
/usr/local/garner/garnerd status
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "`date` $0 :Garner is allready running"
    exit 0
fi
touch /dev/blank
cd /usr/local/garner
uname -a | grep -i cygwin
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    export CYGWIN="$CYGWIN error_start=dumper -d %1 %2"
    /usr/local/garner/garner.exe -n -c /usr/local/garner/conf/garner.conf -p /usr/local/garner/garner.pid -l /usr/local/garner/log/garner.log -L 4   &
else
    /usr/local/garner/garner  -c /usr/local/garner/conf/garner.conf -p /usr/local/garner/garner.pid -l /usr/local/garner/log/garner.log -L 4   &
fi
cd -
```

when I call ./garnerd start, it creates pid file.after that If I see contents of this file, it shows process id of garner.

```
[root@localhost garner]# cat garner.pid
9282
```

But when I check detail information of process id through following command, it shows **"SigBlk: 0000000000000004"** which uses signal 3.

```
[root@localhost garner]# cat /proc/9282/status
Name:   garner
State:  S (sleeping)
SleepAVG:       78%
Tgid:   9282
Pid:    9282
PPid:   9281
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       0       0       0
FDSize: 64
Groups: 0 1 2 3 4 6 10
VmPeak:    58888 kB
VmSize:    58884 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:      7124 kB
VmRSS:      7124 kB
VmData:    17192 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:        84 kB
VmLib:      4480 kB
VmPTE:       156 kB
StaBrk: 05af0000 kB
Brk:    060ec000 kB
StaStk: 7fff0329d950 kB
Threads:        2
SigQ:   0/47721
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000004
SigIgn: 0000000000001002
SigCgt: 0400000180006005
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 00000000fffffeff
CapEff: 00000000fffffeff
Cpus_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00ffffff
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000003
```

And If I manually run command(./garnerd start) from linux machine, it shows **"SigBlk: 0000000000000000"**.
It means Java Blocks the processes? if yes then why and in which circumstances??

Comment: You can use apache commons exec for running commands from java. It has methods to handle the I/P, O/P streams which prevent from the buffer to fill and blocking of process.

Answer (score 5):

From the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) of `java.lang.Process`:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

[This article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) explains the issue in detail and suggests a solution.

Comment: thanks for your reply but still I am not clear about your answer.. :) ..please help to get this solve.

Comment: @Michael.. I 've read and tried example given in article (i.e..4.3,4.4)..but still the same problem i am facing.