# When/why does Java Runtime.exec() require cmd.exe?

Tags: java

In my Java code I have found quite significant performance differences between two similar commands:

```
execString=new String[]{"CMD.EXE","/C", path_to_executable };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

runs my executable almost twice as quickly (6-7mins vs 3-4mins) as:

```
execString=new String[]{" path_to_executable };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

Please can someone educate me as to why?  One seems to be telling the executable to run directly, whereas the other is telling cmd.exe to run the executable...?

Thanks in advance :-)

*EDIT:
The same performance discrepancies were noted when using ProcessBuilder:*

```
ProcessBuilder myPB = new ProcessBuilder(execString);
Process myProcess = myPB.start();
```

Comment: Can you show us these timings? This *might* be a problem with how your benchmarking it.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is another option to consider; why are you using `Runtime.exec(String[])`? And what/where are you timing?

Comment: In fact I am using ProcessBuilder in my actual code, but I understand that it simply calls Runtime.exec anyway so have omitted it in the above example.  I get the same result in any case whether I use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec directly.  When I time the execution of my executable, it takes 6-7mins to complete without cmd.exe, and about 3-4mins with cmd.exe.  Not sure if it's hitting a memory allocation issue (rather than a CPU issue). I just wondered what the inherent differences in the two approaches are.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676491/1961025

> From the API doc of java.lang.Process:
>
> > Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
> > standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
> > stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
> > subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

Basically, you need to make sure that the process is handling the input, output and error streams.  Mine wasn't.  When using cmd.exe, I think it kind of wraps the executable so it's not an issue.  Using the gobblers from https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2 works a treat!

Thanks!